# Cleaning of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in the following format:

```
 Col
 Honda [edit]   
 Accord (4 models)[1]  
 Civic  (4 models)[2]  
 Pilot  (3 models)[1]  
 Toyota [edit]  
 Prius  (4 models)[1]  
 Highlander (3 models)[4]  
 Ford [edit]  
 Explorer (2 models)[1]
```

I want data in the following format:

```
  A         B
  Honda     Accord  
  Honda     Civic  
  Honda     Pilot  
  Toyota    Prius   
  Toyota    Highlander
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? What went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: Also, neither post looks like a valid dataframe. The data needs pre-processing

Answer (score 2):

Create boolean mask for test string `[edit]` by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then split column by whitespace with first `(` or `[`, replace not matched values to `NaN` by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and forward filling missing values to column `A`. Function [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) is for new column to first position. Last remove same values in both columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and create default index by `reset_index`:

```
mask = df['Col'].str.contains('[edit]', regex=False)
df['B'] = df.pop('Col').str.split('\s+\(|\s+\[', n=1).str[0]
df.insert(0, 'A', df['B'].where(mask).ffill())
df = df[df['A'] != df['B']].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        A           B
0   Honda      Accord
1   Honda       Civic
2   Honda       Pilot
3  Toyota       Prius
4  Toyota  Highlander
5    Ford    Explorer
```

Another solution:

```
items = []
for x in df['Col']:
    if x.endswith('[edit]'):
        a = x.rstrip(' [edit]')
    else:       
        b = x.split('(')[0].strip()
        items.append((a, b))

df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['A', 'B'])
print (df)
        A           B
0   Honda      Accord
1   Honda       Civic
2   Honda       Pilot
3  Toyota       Prius
4  Toyota  Highlander
5     For    Explorer
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC 1st find the Col which contain edit by using `str.contains`, the we using `ffill`(all assumed data was orderded) after that we just need clear your data with `str.split`

```
df['A']=df.Col[df.Col.str.contains('edit')]
df.A=df.A.ffill()
df
Out[58]: 
                          Col                A
0             Honda [edit]     Honda [edit]   
1      Accord (4 models)[1]    Honda [edit]   
2      Civic  (4 models)[2]    Honda [edit]   
3      Pilot  (3 models)[1]    Honda [edit]   
4             Toyota [edit]    Toyota [edit]  
5      Prius  (4 models)[1]    Toyota [edit]  
6  Highlander (3 models)[4]    Toyota [edit]  
7               Ford [edit]      Ford [edit]  
8    Explorer (2 models)[1]      Ford [edit]  

df.apply(lambda x : df.Col.str.split(r'[(|[]').str[0],1).query('Col!=A')
Out[59]: 
          Col       A
1      Accord   Honda
2       Civic   Honda
3       Pilot   Honda
5       Prius  Toyota
6  Highlander  Toyota
8    Explorer    Ford
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and support.Wen-Ben and jezrael